# Add soap header to a webservice in .net

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I am trying to access to a webservice in my .net aplication, but the webservice needs credentials.
how can i add the soap header in .net?
the webservice in a NO-.net webservice.

Comment: When you add the web reference in vs does it prompt you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you do something like this?

```
using (var service = new YourWebService())
{
    service.PreAuthenticate = true;
    service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
    var response = service.SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: nope, invalid user and password, my webservice is from oracle

Comment: Are you adding a web reference to your project and specifying the WSDL or how are you attempting access?

Comment: just add the webservice to my project

Comment: You're going to have to supply more information. Show us some code, walk us through the steps you're using to "just add the webservice to [your] project", etc.